# Should rest apis return a message for an enum besides its value?

Tags: api-design

Say, we have an api which returns a list of employee records. Each record has a `gender` field whose value may be `'MALE'` or `'FEMALE'`. We want to show the gender of each employee with a message which may be `'Male'` or `'Female'`.

To achieve the goal above, we have following options:

- Return both the value and the message so the client doesn't bother
- Return the value only and let client determine the appropriate message

Which one is better?

Comment: In a nutshell, I'd prefer the 2nd option as it enables the client to cater for internationalisation (i.e. the client can represent the value `Male` in Chinese, Spanish, etc.).

Comment: @MoA Internationalization can also be done on the server side. Or is this a case where server-side internationalization doesn't fit?

Comment: Yes, this is a case where the API consumer provides internationalization, rather than having it come directly from the API itself.

Comment: @MoA Could you elaborate on why?

Answer (score 1):

It does depend. If you plan to give a uniform vision about your backend data and potentially there will be N API Consumer that will use your service, I'd prefer the first option. This can come in handy if you have to tackle to internationalization issue